# How to boot Raspberry Pi IMG file on QEMU?

Tags: raspberry-pi, qemu, arm

I have an IMG file, which is Raspberry Pi image. Can I boot it in Qemu on windows or linux? I am confused by examples, which say I need not only IMG file, but also a "kernel" file. Can I boot just from IMG?

Here is an example of a command:

```
qemu-system-arm -kernel ~/qemu_vms/<your-kernel-qemu> -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/sda2 rootfstype=ext4 rw" -hda ~/qemu_vms/<your-jessie-image.img> -redir tcp:5022::22 -no-reboot
```

Comment: I don't know very much about this, but I *think* you need a kernel for QEMU because the image itself isn't bootable media. Instead, the physical PI has a bootloader in EEPROM.

Comment: Potentially helpful: https://blog.agchapman.com/using-qemu-to-emulate-a-raspberry-pi/